# How to integrate divergence of vector field over cylinder?

Tags: vector-analysis

For vector field **a**, how can I integrate grad dot **a** over a cylinder bound by $x^2 + y^2 = r^2, 0 < z < h$?

I attempted to do a triple integration but I'm confused about what bounds to use.

Comment: You can express the cylindrical region as $E=\{(x,y,z): -r \leq x\leq r, -\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\leq y \leq \sqrt{r^2-x^2}   , 0\leq z\leq h\}$ in cartesian coordinates or $E=\{(\rho,\theta,z):0\leq\rho\leq r, 0\leq\theta\leq2\pi, 0\leq z\leq h\}$ in cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: Or if you like eyesores, in spherical coordinates as$$E=\left\{(\rho,\theta,\phi) : 0\le\rho\le\min(r\csc(\phi), h\sec(\phi)) \land 0\le\theta\le2\pi \land 0\le\phi\le\pi\right\} \\ = \left\{(\rho,\theta,\phi) : 0\le\rho\le r\csc(\phi) \land 0\le\theta\le2\pi \land 0\le\phi\le\tan^{-1}\left(\frac rh\right)\right\} \cup \left\{(\rho,\theta,\phi) : 0\le\rho\le h\sec(\phi) \land 0\le\theta\le2\pi \land \tan^{-1}\left(\frac rh\right)\le\phi\le\pi\right\}$$

Comment: @upanddownintegrate Thank you, I was concerned by the result being 0 but I wonder now if that was a result of the equation itself rather than the bounds since correcting them gave the same result... appreciate the help!